# Want to change the image src acc to screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, frontend

i want to change the src of the image tag given below to images/hero-desktop.jpg

```
<img src="images/hero-mobile.jpg" alt="" class="image">
```

using javascript
i tried

```
value=800;

if(screen.width > value){
    document.getElementsByClassName('image').src="images/hero-desktop.jpg";
}
```

but it doesnt work. the js file is linked and working(checked by console log).

can anyone help me out????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 1):

It is a silly mistake .

`document.getElementsByClassName('image')` is returning a array .

### why

Now you are thinking while `document.getElementsById` is working fine without `[0]` mean returning specific item but  `document.getElementsByClassName` returning an `array` .

Because `id` is unique for each element while multiple element can have same `class` (for optimize CSS performance ) so always its gonna return a array

In your case u want to access the first element so use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0]
```

## Working Snippet

```js
let value=800;

if(screen.width > value){
    document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0].src="https://picsum.photos/500";
}
console.log(screen.width);
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" class="image">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the picture/srcset/sizes to achieve that.

From MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images):

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg"
     alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for that. Just like @JagadishLenka said, `getElementsByClassName` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

```
const max_width = 800;

if (screen.width > max_width)
    document.querySelector('.image').src = "images/hero-desktop.jpg";
```